# Why doesn't my <p> text show up in my <div>

Tags: html, css

As title states, no matter how long or short my p text is it wont fit into my div attached is code relating to both of them.

```css
p{
font-family: var(--ff-accent);   
position:relative; top:180px;
  text-align:center;
margin: 10px;
margin-bottom: 1em;


.container4 {
margin-inline: auto;
width: min(99%);
height:auto;
background-color:#32779A;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="container4">
  <section class="bg-third">
    <h2 class="light-text">Top Stories This Week!</h2>
    <p>ffffff</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: you lose the `}`

Comment: To be semantically correct, I would nest the container div within the section and have the `p` be the child of the div.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you set `position:relative; top:180px;` to the `p` which means you custom its position so it will be outside the `div`.

Also you lose the `}` for css

```css
p {
  font-family: var(--ff-accent);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.container4 {
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: min(99%);
  height: auto;
  background-color: #32779A;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container4">
  <section class="bg-third">
    <h2 class="light-text">Top Stories This Week!</h2>
    <p>ffffff</p>
  </section>
```

Comment: The positioning would work, if a height would be specified to the `container4`.

Comment: @OttherCreek, I assume the OP want to make the parent div to contain the child p, but it won't be possible if you doesn't grow parent div height, but simply custom child p's position